# How to interpret (document)0[]

Tags: javascript

I saw a code fragment like this:

```
with(document)0[(getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || body).appendChild(createElement(xxx))]
```

I don't know how to understand `with(document)0[]`

Comment: `(document)0 ` gives error in console :/

Comment: That should be a parse error. Where did you come across this?!

Comment: I'm not suprised that you don't understand it - it's nonsense.

Comment: I'm not sure but before edit, code had `with` preceding it. Can that mean something like typescript?

Answer (score 0):

This is not valid JavaScript syntax and, trying to read around that, the semantics are extremely unclear.

I imagine the author meant something like this:

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body.appendChild(createElement(xxx))
```

"If there are any `<head>` tag in the document, return the first. Otherwise return the the result of appending `createElement(xxx)` to the body".

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer this question without the full code. But I'll made some assumptions here.

The first thing that I'd like to say is to avoid of using `with()` statement. It is not recommended in ECMAScript 5 and is forbidden in `strict mode`. And one of the reasons is your fragment - this code confused a lot of people, even you.

So let's rewrite it a little bit to make it more understandable:

```
with(document) {
    0[(getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || body).appendChild(createElement(xxx))];
}
```

How `with` works you can read here - [with statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with),  but basically it is give us an ability to use directly all the properties and methods of the expression that we are sending to `with` (in our case it's a `document`).

So, how this code fragment will looks like without `with`?

```
0[(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body).appendChild(document.createElement(xxx))];
```

The only answer that I don't have is - why to execute this code inside of brackets? The assumption that I have is the following:

this code fragment `(document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0] || document.body).appendChild(document.createElement(xxx))` will return the node of new created element. But if we place this code into the `0[]`, it will return `undefined` as there is no such property. Again, it's hard to understand all parts of this code fragment without the whole picture.

Comment: "with(document)0[(getElementsByTagName('head')[0]||body).appendChild(createElement('script')).src='http://bdimg.share.baidu.com/static/api/js/share.js?cdnversion='+~(-new Date()/36e5)];"  this is the source code,and it's works well;I know with can change the scope;but the 0 how to interpret

Comment: Yes, this code should work well, it's written correctly.
I don't know any 'backstage magic' in js that can do something with `0[]` in this code fragment. The only logical explanation for me is a return value in this fragment. So, after inner expression will be executed, it will return the src, so the code will looks like this: `with(document)0["http://..."];`. To handle this, JS engine will do `new Number(0)` and search for "http://..." property in this new created object and returns `undefined`.
So, because of `0[]` wrapper, this code fragment will return `undefined` instead of `http://...`

Comment: Thank you for your answer;but I think it does not make sense,because No variable to hold a return value